# javascript removing characters from multiple strings using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I'm reading a log file using file reader and then want to do some text manipulation using javascript, to use the read data further in my program. So far I managed to split my input by lines, but now that I want to format the specific strings in the array nothing happens. Is this due to not declaring the array globally? Basically I wanted to do a for loop that checks all the strings inside my array and remove "    " (four blank spaces) that appear at the start for some of my strings. This is my code

```
$("#draftlog").change(function() {
var logFile = $('#draftlog').get(0).files[0]; 
//gets first file from draftlog
var reader = new FileReader;
reader.readAsText(logFile);
reader.onload = function(e) {
var rawLog = reader.result;
//reads first file from draftlog as text
var re=/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/g;
arrayOfLines = rawLog.replace(re,"\n").split("\n");
//splits the text into an array of strings for every new line
for(x=0;x<arrayOfLines.length;x++) {
    arrayOfLines[x].replace(/    /g,'');
}
console.log(arrayOfLines);
};
});
```

my input will typicaly look like this:

```
Event #: 7952945
Time:    5.2.2015 17:14:54
Players:
    TheDoktorJot
    Arlekin
    Jokulgoblin
    Felo
    Petrolit
    Greyjoy
--> Susti
    themuse1975
    n0sfea

------ FRF ------ 

Pack 1 pick 1:
    Abzan Runemark
    Rakshasa's Disdain
    Reach of Shadows
    Grim Contest
    Aven Skirmisher
    Lotus Path Djinn
    Formless Nurturing
    Tasigur's Cruelty
    Temur Battle Rage
    Return to the Earth
--> Temur Sabertooth
    Fascination
    Jeskai Barricade
    Arcbond
    Rugged Highlands

Pack 1 pick 2:
    Sandblast
    Sultai Runemark
    Jeskai Sage
    Hooded Assassin
    Pressure Point
    Gore Swine
    Whisperer of the Wilds
    Mardu Runemark
    Ambush Krotiq
    Write into Being
    Qarsi High Priest
    Hewed Stone Retainers
    Wardscale Dragon
--> Mastery of the Unseen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you have to write it back

```
for(x=0;x<arrayOfLines.length;x++) {
    arrayOfLines[x] = arrayOfLines[x].replace(/    /g,'');
}
```

You could also just trim it to remove leading and following whitespace

```
arrayOfLines[x] = arrayOfLines[x].trim();
```